# Svelte3 input validation

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

Yesterday I was trying to translate a problem I had to solve in React, to Svelte, and I can't figure it out.

The problem is the following:

- I have 3 inputs each one of them holds a percentage.
- The 3 percentages altogether cannot add more than 100.
- I have a fourth input, it's disabled, so it just shows the remaining percentage to 100%

In react is fairly easy, declare a function that takes, the event and a variable to know which input I'm taking the event from. Do the proper validations and done.

Sadly in svelte I have almost 0 experience, and I don't know how to tackle it.
This the code so far (spoiler alert it does not even get close to do what is supposed to do).
[Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/55c88b96d78d4cbfa5f7f659c59ad8a1?version=3.12.1)

Running a console.log to show the value of sp1, inside the function that validates it, and outside the function (before and after the function), shows what I do expect:

- Before the function (before): value in the input
- Inside the function: value validated
- Outside the function (after): value validated

So the validation and assignment of the correct value takes place, nonetheless the input keep showing wrong value (ex: input shows 112 and the value should be 100).

Comment: Please add some code which you already tried, I'm afraid nobody will write the code for you...

Comment: The code is already provided in the link  "Svelte REPL"
I tought it was clearly visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more dynamic way to do this would be using arrays.

```js
let inputs = [{
    value: 0,
    color: 'GRAY'
}, {
    value: 0,
    color: 'DARKSLATEGRAY'
}, {
    value: 0,
    color: 'TEAL'
}];
```

This would also make calculations easier since we can use the array methods. It would also enable us to use `each` blocks which remove redundant code. Then we will use a function called `validate` and pass the index of the current input to it. Using the `input` we can calculate the maximum possible value that can be entered in that `input` and set the `input` if it crosses that maximum value. This `validate` function will be called from the template on the `input` event.

Here's the code.

```
<script>
    let total = 100;
    let inputs = [{
        value: 0,
        color: 'GRAY'
    }, {
        value: 0,
        color: 'DARKSLATEGRAY'
    }, {
        value: 0,
        color: 'TEAL'
    }];
    $: spOthers = total - inputs.map(x => x.value || 0).reduce((a, b) => a + b);

    function validate(index) {
        let maxInput = total - inputs.map(x => x.value).filter((x, i) => i !== index).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
        if (inputs[index].value > maxInput) {
            inputs[index].value = maxInput;
        }
    }
</script>

{#each inputs as {value, color}, i}
    <div class='input-container'>
        <div class='square' style="background-color: {color}" />
        <input type="number" min="0" class='input' bind:value={value} on:input={() => validate(i)} />
    </div>
{/each}
<div class='input-container'>
    <div class='square' style="background-color: DARKORANGE" />
    <input type='number' class='input input-others' bind:value={spOthers} disabled/>
</div>
```

**Note**: I have omitted the styles above as there are no changes in them.

Here is a working [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/052c877eb34c45ee8f773a8bf8475347?version=3.12.1).

Comment: Thanks! I really like the solution, this is exactly what I was searching for :)

Answer (score 0):

Nice. You can also do:

```
$: spOthers = inputs.reduce((a, c, i, inputs) => a + c.value, 0);

function validate(index) {
    const delta = spOthers - total;
    if (delta > 0) {
        inputs[index].value -= delta;   
    }
}
```